# How can I avoid getting Error 403: Forbidden when trying to get file by URL

Tags: python, image, python-requests, discord.py, urllib

I have a Discord.py bot that connects to a `MySQL database`.
I want to retrieve a user's banner `URL` from the database based on their `Discord user ID`.
After retrieving the URL, I use `urllib.request.urlretrieve` to download the image and save it to a `local file`.
I receive a urllib.error.HTTPError or a urllib.error.URLError with a 403 (Forbidden) error when attempting to download the image.

```py
@commands.slash_command(name="profile", description="Fetch user data")
async def profile(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.User):

    cursor.execute("SELECT banner_url FROM user_ui WHERE user_id = %s", (user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if result:

        print(result)
        url = result[0]
        full_path = "assets/banner.jpg"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

        banner = "assets/banner.jpg"
```

```
0.09 13:49:59 [Bot] discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

- I have ensured that the MySQL database connection works correctly.
- The Pycord bot operates as expected for other commands and functionalities.
- I have checked the URL, and it appears to be valid.
- I suspect that there may be an issue with how I'm downloading and saving the image from the URL.

I would like to understand why I'm receiving the 403 error when attempting to download the image and how to resolve it. If there are any improvements or corrections needed in my code snippet, please provide guidance.

Comment: 403 generally means that the server doesn't want to talk to you.  Maybe it doesn't like your IP address domain, or maybe it thinks you're a bot.

Comment: yeah but how can I solve it, I know what 403 means.

Comment: Are you able to set headers on the request?  One common way that a site decides you're a bot is to look at the user-agent header on the request.

Comment: so like: user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/102.0.0.0"

url = result[0]
full_path = "assets/banner.jpg"

# Create a request object with a User-Agent header
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})

 with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
        with open(full_path, 'wb') as out_file:
            out_file.write(response.read())

?

Comment: Like that, yes.

Comment: That did not work, either, maybe I could save the images before locally, then put the url in the db, and then match url db with local saved images?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I played a bit with it and came to the solution to save it before storing in the database and then matching the names when I use ut again